# Prevent iPhone use after hours

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to prevent myself from using my iPhone (except say for messages or phone calls) between certain hours?

If it is not possible with a existing feature (or app?), is there something in macOS Server (or other "enterprise" tool) that would help?

I would like to get in the habit of not using my iPhone before bed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has introduced ScreenTime in iOS 12:

https://www.apple.com/au/newsroom/2018/06/ios-12-introduces-new-features-to-reduce-interruptions-and-manage-screen-time/

You can place limits on each app.

Answer (score 4):

### You are in control. It is your responsibility.

Here are some suggestions you could try:

- To help you keeping focus try a 'Stay focussed' app like [Forest](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/forest-stay-focused-be-present/id866450515) (which tries to convince you not to use your phone while the app is running).
- To create a threshold you can enable restrictions. Go to `Settings` -> `General` -> `Restrictions`.
- Shutdown your phone. The boot time will keep you from using your phone.
- Edit settings in your router, some router can set internet access restrictions for certain devices during specified hours.

Comment: What does forest do? Shutting the phone stops phone calls which the OP wants

Comment: "Is it possible to prevent myself from using my iPhone between certain hours?" I interpreted the use of messages and phone calls as an example. And indeed, not all answers might be benefitial for this user, but can benefit another user.

Comment: OP says except and not example

Answer (score 1):

This link shows a way to restrict Internet access during certain times:

- [4 Ways to Manage Your Kids’ Internet Use With Your Router](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-ways-to-manage-your-kids-internet-use-with-your-router/)

Your router might be different so try looking at your router manual, may be it has a similar feature. But as CousinCocaine said, "You are in control..." that would be best strategy.

Or:

If you live with someone, ask them to take your phone between particular times. The only way you should be allowed to get your phone (except for phone calls) is by paying 5$ per min. That way the other person will have lots of motivation to keep an eye on you.